libpq5 doesn' see libldap on Ubuntu 22.04
I try to install libpq5 but it doesn't see libldap
Run
sudo apt-get install libpq5  

Got
The following packages have unmet dependencies:


libpq5 : Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not installable

    


apt policy libpq5


Libldap is installed correctly:
sudo apt-get install libldap-2.5-0 


How to install libpq5 properly on Ubuntu 22.04?

Where did you get your libpq5? What does apt policy libpq5 show? The 22.04 libpq5 correctly depends on libldap-2.5-0, not libldap-2.4-2.

How to know where I get there? | just run apt-get install libpq5

As I said, what does apt policy libpq5 show?

It shows https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/focal

apt is pulling libpq5 from a repository which is not appropriate for your system. To fix this, remove entries in /etc/apt/sources.list and files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d pointing to ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/focal, and install the 22.04 version of libpq5:
sudo apt install libpq5/jammy


Thanks, I had problems installing QGIS because of a "jammy" lbpq5, due to obsolete pgadmin4 refs in /etc/apt/sources/list.d/ files!!! Now it works!
